# jQuery Datatables sDom pushes columnFilterWidget to the left (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, datatables

I use bootstrap, jQuery Datatables and [columnFilterWidgets.js](https://github.com/cyberhobo/ColumnFilterWidgets)

Under Firefox it goes terrible wrong (columnfilterwidget.js pushes itself to the left of the table) when I use this sDom-Declaration:

```
"sDom": 'W<"clear">lrtip',
```

[image]

**Instead** When I use this sDom-declaration:

```
"sDom": '<"H"W>lrtip'
```

The filter appears above the table. **But** there is this little white line (because of the **<"H">** )

[image]

**I want to use the first sDom-Declaration, but it should be displayed correctly with Firefox. Where do you think is the error? I have no idea! Nothing in the Chrome-Console ...**

Comment: can you add your table definition? datatables version..? bJQueryUI is true or false?

Comment: entire code needed to figure out the issue....

Answer (score 2):

A few things: Are you including the columnFilterWidget css?  There is a css file which contains these style definitions.  Be sure to include them:

```
.column-filter-widget { float:left; padding: 5px; }
.column-filter-widget select { display: block; }
.column-filter-widgets a.filter-term { display: block; text-decoration: none; padding-left: 10px; font-size: 90%; }
.column-filter-widgets a.filter-term:hover { text-decoration: line-through !important; }
.column-filter-widget-selected-terms { clear:left; }
```

For me, it works better with this sDom: `"sDom": 'lfrWtip'`

If you must use `"sDom": '<"H"W>lrtip'`, what is your css class "H" defined as?  the <"H"W> says to include the widget (W) in a DIV with a class of "H".  So either your H class introduces the white line, or the DIV is inheriting the white line from another css class.

Comment: Grace period ends in 30 minutes. I think your answers were helpful, so I give you +1 at least.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to make similar setup in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/G8WZb/3/

So it seems that you just need new background image and thats all. So I used transparent background and then I made new background for whole table wrapper, which is behind filters and table header. I just made gradient behind it, but it is better to have also a picture there.

Since you didnt send a css or name of theme that you use for jqueryUI, then I cant provide more accurate help.

HTML:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example" style="width:980px">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rendering engine</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 4.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center">4</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeC">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center">5</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center">5.5</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 6</td>
            <td>Win 98+</td>
            <td class="center">6</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
            <td>Win XP SP2+</td>
            <td class="center">7</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>AOL browser (AOL desktop)</td>
            <td>Win XP</td>
            <td class="center">6</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 1.0</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.7</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 1.5</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 2.0</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 3.0</td>
            <td>Win 2k+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td class="center">1.9</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Camino 1.0</td>
            <td>OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Camino 1.5</td>
            <td>OSX.3+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape 7.2</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2</td>
            <td class="center">1.7</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape Browser 8</td>
            <td>Win 98SE+</td>
            <td class="center">1.7</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape Navigator 9</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.1</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.1</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.2</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.2</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.3</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.3</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.4</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.4</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.5</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.6</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.6</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.7</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.7</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.8</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Seamonkey 1.1</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Epiphany 2.20</td>
            <td>Gnome</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 1.2</td>
            <td>OSX.3</td>
            <td class="center">125.5</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 1.3</td>
            <td>OSX.3</td>
            <td class="center">312.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 2.0</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td class="center">419.3</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 3.0</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td class="center">522.1</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Google Chrome 1.0</td>
            <td>Win XP+</td>
            <td class="center">525</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>OmniWeb 5.5</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td class="center">420</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>iPod Touch / iPhone</td>
            <td>iPod</td>
            <td class="center">420.1</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>S60</td>
            <td>S60</td>
            <td class="center">413</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 7.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 7.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 8.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 8.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.2</td>
            <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.5</td>
            <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera for Wii</td>
            <td>Wii</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Nokia N800</td>
            <td>N800</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Nintendo DS browser</td>
            <td>Nintendo DS</td>
            <td class="center">8.5</td>
            <td class="center">C/A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeC">
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.1</td>
            <td>KDE 3.1</td>
            <td class="center">3.1</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.3</td>
            <td>KDE 3.3</td>
            <td class="center">3.3</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.5</td>
            <td>KDE 3.5</td>
            <td class="center">3.5</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 4.5</td>
            <td>Mac OS 8-9</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeC">
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.1</td>
            <td>Mac OS 7.6-9</td>
            <td class="center">1</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeC">
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.2</td>
            <td>Mac OS 8-X</td>
            <td class="center">1</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>NetFront 3.1</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>NetFront 3.4</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Dillo 0.8</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Links</td>
            <td>Text only</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Lynx</td>
            <td>Text only</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeC">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>IE Mobile</td>
            <td>Windows Mobile 6</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeC">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>PSP browser</td>
            <td>PSP</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeU">
            <td>Other browsers</td>
            <td>All others</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">U</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.column-filter-widget {
    float:left;
    padding: 5px;
}
.column-filter-widget select {
    display: block;
}
.column-filter-widgets a.filter-term {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 90%;
}
.column-filter-widgets a.filter-term:hover {
    text-decoration: line-through !important;
}
.column-filter-widget-selected-terms {
    clear:left;
}

#example_wrapper {

    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F4F3F8 0%, #ECEBF1 50px); /* here I changed background-image */
    background-color: #ECEBF1; /* you need special img as a fallback for IE7,8,9 or there will be no gradient */

    /* just delete the rest */
    border: solid #CDCCD1 1px; 
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
        "sDom": 'W<"clear">lrtip'
});
```

external resources:

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

http://datatables.net/extras/thirdparty/ColumnFilterWidgets/DataTables/extras/ColumnFilterWidgets/media/js/ColumnFilterWidgets.js

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/media/css/demo_table_jui.css

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can solve that with css. It's difficult to understand what's causing this bug in firefox without the entire code, but with the given print screen, it seems that the table header height is too small. maybe you can use something like that:

```
.ui-widget-header{ /* or maybe a better selector for your jQueryUI theme "header"*/
    height:auto; /* or a bigger value */
}
```